# Rails : Stripe : Updating existing subscription with new coupon code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, coupon

I have a subscription and if I update it with `coupon` how is the coupon going to apply? Client has already paid the amount and now I am going to apply a 100% discount coupon by editing from my admin dashboard.

How is this handled?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I did.

First I updated the customer's subscription:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
subscription = customer.retrieve(subscription_id)
subscription.coupon = "coupon_id"
subscription.save
```

The customer's subscription is then updated with details of the `coupon` in the discount hash.

Then I manually refunded the `charge` object of that customer(if the coupon is 100% discount coupon).

```
charge = customer.retrieve(stripe_charge_id)
refund = charge.refund
```

This then updates the `charge` object with `amount_refunded` with the discounted amount after applying the coupon. Also `refunded` is set to true with updated `refunds` hash.

You can also create a refund for certain amount by passing the amount, like:

```
re = Stripe::Refund.create(  
                           charge: charge_id,
                           amount: amount_you_want_to_refund
                          )
```

For the upcoming invoices, the invoice is created for that discounted amount.

Comment: means, if we do not refund manually, the discount will apply only to upcoming invoices?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you'd update an existing subscription with a coupon in Ruby:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_...")
subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_...")
subscription.coupon = "coupon_code"
subscription.save
```

The coupon will apply to the next invoice(s) for this subscription, but the past invoices will not be affected.

Comment: but what if I added coupon in middle of the subscription month/year?

Comment: As I said, the discount would apply to the next invoice or invoices.

Comment: It means I need to manually refund the previous charges, right ?